# Strictly convex renormings making power bounded operators into contractions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T$ be a power bounded linear operator on $X$ (i.e. $\sup_{n\ge0}\|T^n\|_{op}<\infty$). We can of course define an equivalent norm $\|\cdot\|'$ on $X$ so that $\|T\|'_{op} \le 1$ by setting $\|x\|'=\sup_{n\ge 0}\|T^nx\|$.

Assuming either that $X$ is separable or it has separable predual and $T$ is weak-$^*$ continuous, are there any conditions known on $X$ and $T$ that are sufficient for there to be an equivalent *strictly convex* norm $\|\cdot\|''$ on $X$ with $\|T\|''_{op}\le 1$? What if we no longer insist that $\|\cdot\|''$ is equivalent to $\|\cdot\|$, can anything be said in this case?